# Excel-Custom-Functions sample code not working because of undefined ExtensionPoint "CustomFunctions"

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

The `manifest.xml` in the [Excel Custom Functions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions) sample does not validate because the `ExtensionPoint` `CustomFunctions` does not exist in `TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd`.

Resulting error message is:

> This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides:CustomFunctions'.

Is there a newer version of `TaskPaneAppVersionOverrides.xsd` that I can refer to in order to get the sample code working?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the public schema (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/live/docs/overview/schemas/taskpane/TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd) has not been updated with the custom function changes during the preview.

For now you should go ahead with testing and development without validating your manifest against the schema xsd.

I think your feedback is good here - we should release a preview xsd file somewhere to help make your development easier. I'll work on that and post an update here. Thank you!

-Michael, PM for add-ins